# axios then/catch code executed at last

Tags: javascript, axios

Using the JS library axios, why the does the code in the .then/.catch section is exucted at last?

```
save(data) {
    axios.put('/api/persons/1', data)
        .then(response => {
            alert('hello')
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert('goodbye')
        })
    alert('world')
}
```

This function shows a 1st alert 'world' and 2nd 'hello'

Comment: I would suggest you looking in promises/async code... Because that's basic understanding of async programing. the .then() and .catch() will run at a later time.

Comment: thank you @WilomGfx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `alert('world')` is processed in the same tick as the `put`.